# What is the fruit of the Chinese windmill palm, and is it edible?

Tags: trees, fruits, palm

We have two large Chinese windmill palm trees in our front garden here in Essex, England. They're around 15 feet tall, and absolutely beautiful.

They have a large amount of fruit near the top, small dark purple berries on bright yellow/orange stems.

I'm curious as to what they are, whether they're edible. I know acai come from palm trees, wondering if these are anything similar.

Comment: Hi Lukech. Would you mind posting a couple of pictures?  I don't know this palm, and would love to see what the plant looks like, including the flowers and fruit. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The fruit is usually not consumed, but is occasionally used for medical purposes in some countries - it has a haemostatic effect, meaning it clots blood, and may be used to make a solution for use as a contraceptive. There are more efficient ways to do both those things, obviously; it doesn't  sound like the fruits are eaten for their flavour.

Its interesting you've got fruit though - it means they are female plants, and there must be a male in the vicinity somewhere for fruit to be produced.  Other parts of the plant can be used for edible purposes, see here http://www.pfaf.org/user/plant.aspx?latinname=Trachycarpus+fortunei

Comment: Yes, we have two, one with fruit and one without, side by side in the front garden :)

Comment: Ah,, well then the one without fruit must be male...